# Missing IMultiValueConverter Interface?

Tags: c#, missing-data, imultivalueconverter

I'm just wondering, but I thought MS implemented a IMultiValueConverter...
SDK 4.5 is installed

[image]

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) is located in the PresentationFramework.dll - Are you sure you've referenced it?

Comment: I tried it, but then there occur errors ...

Comment: The PresentationFramework.dll is used for WPF, but from the screenshot you have a Windows Phone project. The two aren't compatible. I haven't done phone projects, but IMultiValueConverter might not be available. A quick search doesn't show that it is.